# $D^m \cong D^n$ iff $m=n$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

$D^m \cong D^n$ iff $m=n$ here $D^n$ is $n$-dimensional closed unit disc. Since $D^n$s are contractible, we can not simply compare their homology groups. I'm not sure if homeomorphism takes interior to interior then it reduces to compare $S^n$. Do you have idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know that the same statement for spheres is true, then you can consider removing one point from each disc.

Comment: @MathDrifter I understand it now, Thank you.

Comment: By the way, any homeomorphism takes interiors to interiors since interiors have a topological characterization.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why "then it reduces to compare $S^n$".

Comment: And  I do not understand @MathDrifter 's hint either. If it were open disks, [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) would answer the question.

Comment: @Anne: suppose $f : D^n \to D^m$ is a homeomorphism. As Kenta says, a homeomorphism takes interiors to interiors, so $f(x) = y$ for some interior points $x$ and $y$. Deleting these points, $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism $D^n \setminus \{ x \} \to D^m \setminus \{ y \}$. These spaces (for any choice of interior points $x, y$) are homotopy equivalent to $S^n$ and $S^m$ respectively, so any way you have of distinguishing spheres up to homotopy suffices to conclude.

Comment: Alternatively, $f$ must restrict to a homeomorphism from the complement of the interior to the complement of the interior, so in fact gives a homeomorphism $S^n \to S^m$, not just a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @Anna: I don't mean the interior in the topological sense, I mean in the manifold sense. For an $n$-manifold $M$ possibly with boundary its *interior* consists of all points with neighborhoods homeomorphic to neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is a topological definition of the complement of the boundary so it's invariant under homeomorphisms. The collision of terminology is unfortunate, admittedly.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you!

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions to convey important information. The body of the question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure if homeomorphism takes interior to interior then it reduces to compare $S^n$.

Yes, this is true. But this is not straight forward, and in fact requires [the invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

There is a simpler argument though. Let $f:D^n\to D^m$ be a homeomorphism. Then $f$ induces a homeomorphism between $D^n\backslash \{0\}\to D^m\backslash \{f(0)\}$. Now $D^n\backslash \{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$. On the other hand $D^m\backslash \{f(0)\}$ is either homotopy equivalent to $S^{m-1}$ or contractible, depending on whether $f(0)$ is in the interior or on the boundary (which cannot happen for other, more complicated reasons). Either way it cannot be homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$ for $n\neq m$, by comparing homology groups.